# Загадки ЕГЭ: неправильное решение или ошибка в ответе?

Tags: стилистика, егэ

Дано задание. **Установите соответствие** между грамматическими ошибками и предложениями, в которых они допущены.

Предложение: ***В конце XIX — начале XX вв. в русской литературе противопоставивший себя реализму и представленный несколькими литературными течениями: символизмом, акмеизмом, футуризмом — оформился модернизм.***

Виды ошибок:

(1) нарушение в построении предложения с деепричастным оборотом

(2) нарушение в построении предложения с причастным оборотом

(3) нарушение в построении предложения с однородными членами

(4) нарушение в образовании предложно-падежной формы место имения

(5) нарушение связи подлежащего и сказуемого

**Рассуждение ученика**

Предложение выглядит **странно** – в частности, сложно  найти **определяемое слово** («в литературе» или «модернизм»).

Может быть, пропущена запятая и выбраны неверные окончания? Но считается, что знаки исправлять не надо. Если определяемое слово – это «модернизм», то причастный оборот находится на расстоянии от него. Это неверно? Но ведь дистантное расположение оборота в принципе возможно.

Все-таки ученик выбирает **ошибку 2 как наиболее вероятную** (нарушение в построении предложения с причастным оборотом). Ему ставят минус за ответ. Но тогда остается ошибка 5 (нарушение связи подлежащего и сказуемого)? А в чем оно заключается?

**Вопросы**

(1) **Так какой ответ верен и почему?** Как выглядит правильное предложение? Может быть, это педагог ошибся при проверке? Как ученику защитить свое мнение?

(2) Можно ли корректно записать предложение **с дистантным расположением** оборота и как тогда правильно расставить знаки?

Спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136712/discussion-on-question-by-sharon-------).